# R: How can I make a barplot with labels parallel (horizontal) to bars

Tags: r, label, bar-chart

In barplot, is it possible to make the labels parallel to the bars?

Suppose we have the data frame called "data".

```
              Page   PV UniquePgv
1 /photos/upcoming 5295      2733
2                / 4821      2996
3          /search 1201       605
4       /my_photos  827       340
5   /photos/circle  732       482
```

I want to make a barplot of PV with the Page column as the label.

```
names <-data$Page
barplot(data$PV,main="Page Views", horiz=TRUE,names.arg=names)
```

Which Produces:

[image]

The name of each bar is vertical, while the bars are horizontal.

How can I make the labels display horizontally and parallel with the bars?  If it is not possible, I am open to suggestions for other ways to plot this information.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is anything in there to change the way the labels are displayed.  Do you have any suggestions on a different way to plot this information?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `las` graphics parameter.  However, if you do that, the names will run off the end of the window, so you need to change the margins.  For example:

```
par(mai=c(1,2,1,1))
barplot(data$PV,main="Page Views", horiz=TRUE,names.arg=names,las=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
esal = c(res$V3)
ename = res$V2
barplot(esal, names.arg=ename, col=c(rainbow(length(esal))),
        xlab="Employee Name", ylab="Salary", main="Emp V/S Salary")
```

[image]

[image]